# How to split the text in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column  which contain of countrycode and Device. For example, JPPHONE,UAEDESKTOP and I want to separate a new column as JP and PHONE , UAE and DESKTOP [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEo2Q.png)

Could you please advise how can i do that?

Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: do you have list of devices used in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of ways to handle this I may approach it differently depending on how all the data is represented.

Below is one way.

```sql
WITH sample AS
(
SELECT 'UAEPHONE' AS combined
UNION ALL SELECT 'DEPHONE'
UNION ALL SELECT 'UKDESKTOP'
UNION ALL SELECT 'USAPHONE'
),
processed as (
SELECT *, CHARACTER_LENGTH(combined) as string_length,
CASE 
    WHEN CONTAINS_SUBSTR(combined, 'PHONE') THEN CHARACTER_LENGTH(combined) - 5
    WHEN CONTAINS_SUBSTR(combined, 'DESKTOP') THEN CHARACTER_LENGTH(combined) - 7
    ELSE NULL
END AS spilt_location

FROM sample
)

SELECT SUBSTR(combined,0,spilt_location) as cc, SUBSTR(combined,spilt_location + 1) as device
FROM processed
```

*Results*

| row | cc | device |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UAE | PHONE |
| 2 | DE | PHONE |
| 3 | UK | DESKTOP |
| 4 | USA | PHONE |

Comment: wow, Thank you ^_^

Comment: No problem, If this answers your question would accept it as the answer.

Comment: may i ask another question? how can i combine that query above to another query ? like SELECT
  yyyy_mm_dd , cc, device
  
FROM
  `xxxx table'

Comment: So  replace `FROM sample`
with the `FROM XXXX table`

Then SELECT whatever properties you want and add whatever clauses you want on the main part of the query.

Comment: Do accept one of the answers. FYI: @Mikhail Berlyant solution is more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select x[safe_offset(0)] as cc, x[safe_offset(1)] as device
from your_table,
unnest([struct(split(
  regexp_replace(col, r'(.*?)(PHONE|DESKTOP)', r'\1,\2')
) as x)])
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]